# Creating RegEx That Reads Entire String

Tags: string-matching, greedy, regex-greedy

My current regex is only picking up part of my string. It creates a match as soon as one if found, even though I need the longer version of that match to hit. For example, I am creating matches for both:

```
SSS111
```

and

```
SSS111-L
```

The first SSS111 matches fine with my current regex, but the `SSS111-L` is only getting matched to the SSS111, leaving the **-L** out.

How can I create a greedy regex to read the whole line before matching? I am currently using

```
[-A-Z0-9]{3,12}
```

to capture the numbers and letters, but have not had any luck outside of this.

Answer (score 0):

Regex are allways greedy. This ist mostly the Problem.
Here i think you have only to escape the '-'

@"[-A-Z]{3-12}"

Comment: Thanks, I think I can see what you were doing. That didn't seem to work though. Hmmm...

Comment: Ok which Programming Language are you use

Comment: Thank you, I tried thew new answer, unfortunately, still no luck.